# How to validate user

Tags: hash, md5, salt

I am inserting password usinh Salt MD5 method. Below is my code

```
  protected string GenerateSalt()
{
    byte[] data = new byte[0x10];
    new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(data);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
}
 private string HashPassword(string password, string salt)
 {
     // Create an MD5 hash of the supplied password using the supplied salt as well.
     string sourceText = salt + password;
     ASCIIEncoding asciiEnc = new ASCIIEncoding();
     string hash = null;
     byte[] byteSourceText = asciiEnc.GetBytes(sourceText);
     MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
     byte[] byteHash = md5Hash.ComputeHash(byteSourceText);
     foreach (byte b in byteHash)
     {
         hash += b.ToString("x2");
     }

     // Return the hashed password
     return hash;
 }
```

here I am using to create the password.

```
 string salt = GenerateSalt();

  string password = HashPassword(txtpassword.Text, salt);
```

it is working fine and saving the password in database.

But when I try to login in the password doesn't match.

below is my code for matching the password and user id

```
 string password = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(txtPassword.Text, "md5").ToString();
            SqlCommand com11 = new SqlCommand("For_Login1", con);
            com11.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Id", ddl.SelectedItem.Text);
            com11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
```

but password didn't match why?

Comment: You need to store your salt and concatenate it with the user's password on login as well. Also, don't use MD5 for this, it's not secure. Try bcrypt instead.

Comment: How to implement ? any link?

Answer (score 1):

`salt` is a final static string (doesn't change) and is usually kept in the DB attached to the hashed password. One convention is to save it as `hash(pwd+salt):salt`.

You're generating a new salt every time you call `generate()` because of the following line:

```
new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(data);
```

which means that you'll never be able to authenticate.

Comment: How to implement it? any reference? any link? or something you should share?

Comment: You should concatenate the salt to the password before **hashing** it (not encrypting, you want this to be one way).

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I have the feeling that you didn't understand what I wrote. I wasn't referring to the encryption (okay okay hashing...) at all, I was referring to the fact that the same salt should be used with the same password, and as a side-note I mentioned that the salt is saved in the DB as well - usually like this `hash(pwd+salt):salt` and to the first part: `hash(pwd+salt)` I was referring as `<enc-pwd>`

Comment: @Gaurav here are a couple of links: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right and https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm